# unable to open X server

Tags: import, imagemagick, xvfb

I am trying to generate a screenshot of a firefox window in my terminal, but I  keep getting an error:

```
root@host [~]# DISPLAY=:1 firefox http://www.cnn.com & sleep 5 && DISPLAY=:1 import -window root -crop 1264x948+0+25 -quality 90 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/screenshot1.jpg && pkill firefox
[1] 30200
import: unable to open X server `:1' @ import.c/ImportImageCommand/364.
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try `DISPLAY=:0`, for example?

Comment: Let me try but why would that change it?

Comment: Same problem import: unable to open X server `:0' @ import.c/ImportImageCommand/364.

Comment: Maybe you should add `XAUTHORITY=/home/youruser/.Xauthority`? Or are you in X as root?

Comment: I dont know. This is all i see and the screenshot comes out black

Comment: nevermind it did not work, i keep getting the error message unable to start x server

Comment: omg lmfao let me see and try that why doesnt xserver run when i restart linux hmm

Comment: Are you doing that on console?

Comment: I'm lost and gone to sleep :)

Comment: Hmm i ran startx and it started but i still get the same thing maybe i started it wrong

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used changed to root in the terminal after starting it (or did you login to X as root?). If that's the case the display can't be opened because it's owned by another user and you can't just go and display stuff somebody else's display.

Exit the root session and it will probably work. If you want it to work from the root session take a look at 'man xhost'.

Comment: Yeah i logged in as root. let me check this out man xhost right?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what are the result when you type

```
ls -la /tmp/ | grep X
```

and

```
ps | grep X
```

Also, I had some trouble with using the DISPLAY=:1 syntax, so instead I use:

```
firefox --display=:1 URL_OF_SITE
import -display :1 -window root etc...
```